# Changing .vue files in Laravel are automatically changing unrelated CSS

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js, npm-run

I'm working on a project in Laravel in which I'm building Vue components. Whenever I make any changes to a .vue file and stage it for a commit, changes are also made to the app.css and app.js files that I didn't do, specifically undoing the same bit of css from a commit from a while ago. My boss and I think that it's an issue with the compiler-- if so, is there a way to prevent the compiler from behaving this way? If it's not the compiler, does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: Are this CSS and JS files written by yourself, or are they generated by a watch task (webpack, or something like that)?

Comment: The CSS and JS are Bootstrap 4, but the changes that are being made automatically are to rules that I added to the CSS file myself and pieces of the JS that pertain to those rules

Comment: Are you editing `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js` directly and then the changes are getting overwritten?

Comment: Yes, but the edits to ```public/css/app.css``` and ```public/js/app.js``` were made in previous commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) which is a wrapper around [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for compiling your js and scss files. This also includes your Vue files which are compiled as part of your `app.js`. This is perfectly normal behaviour.

By default the compiler reads your js and sass files from the `resources` directory and compiles them into `public/js/app.js` and `public/css/app.css`. You should not be directly coding into those two files in the `public` directory otherwise every time you compile those files will be overwritten!

Write all your js and css code in the `resources` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm brand new to Laravel, and the curve can feel pretty steep at times. This was a big help!!

Comment: https://laracasts.com/ have great tutorials focused on Laravel and Vue. Helped me a lot when I first started. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug which sometimes occurs if you are using

```
npm run watch
```

as a script to check for file changes.

You could try to use

```
npm run watch -poll
```

This will periodically & manually (every second for instance) check for changes.